# loadNibNamed, view shifted up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using loadView to programatically setup a UIViewController subclass and was wondering if I am getting it right. When I look at my "Interface.xib" in Interface Builder its view says 0,20,320,460 with the Status bar at the top. My question is when I build the application the view is shifted up (i.e. ignoring the Status bar). I am correcting this by setting the views frame, but am a little curious why its not coming in from the xib file?

```
- (void)loadView {
    NSLog(@"HYBRID UI: %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    NSArray *nibArchive = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Interface" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *nibView = [nibArchive lastObject];
    [nibView setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    [self setView: nibView];
}
```

cheers gary

Comment: What is the parent view of the view you are loading? The frame coordinates are relative to the parent view. I have issues like this when view and parent use applicationFrame (though that shifts down, not up).

Comment: Also: when do you load the view? Is it possible the view is added to the hierarchy at a time when the parent view has a different size (e.g. CGRectZero) and the view is getting resized by layoutSubviews?

Comment: The parent is window, I am adding this view from the Application Delegate using [window addSubview:[[self controller] view]]; its only a very simple test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the view, when loaded from main bundle, doesn't get it's bound in the superview context. Hence getting (x, y) = (0, 0).
You should try to move your view to whatever (x, y) in your xib and watch if this changes anything.

Comment: This is probably correct. Use `NSLog(@"Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(nibView.frame));` to confirm the frame's origin after loading.

Comment: Before I use setFrame the frame that is coming from the UIView is Frame: {{0, 0}, {320, 460}} What I was puzzled about is that if I look in IB using the view size inspector it says [0,20,320,460]